# Count the frequncy of words in a cell of a column in a series

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas

I want to calculate the frequency of the words in obama['text'] (obama is the variable where i have stored this series element ) in a dictionary  and store it in another column . Without using Counter library , how do i do that . The data is in this format :

```
 URI                                      |              name                |  text 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama>           Barack Obama               barack hussein obama ii brk husen bm born august 4 1961 is the 44th and current president of the united states and the first african american to hold the office born in honolulu hawaii obama is a graduate of columbia university and harvard law school where he served as president of the harvard law review he was a community organizer in chicago before earning his law degree he worked as a civil rights attorney and taught constitutional law at the university of chicago law school from 1992 to 2004 he served three terms representing the 13th district in the illinois senate from 1997 to 2004 running unsuccessfully for the united states house of representatives in 2000in 2004 obama received national attention during his campaign to represent illinois in the united states senate with his victory in the march democratic party primary his keynote address at the democratic national convention in july and his election to the senate in november he began his presidential campaign in 2007 and after a close primary campaign against hillary rodham clinton in 2008 he won sufficient delegates in the democratic party primaries to receive the presidential nomination he then defeated republican nominee john mccain in the general election and was inaugurated as president on january 20 2009 nine months after his election obama was named the 2009 nobel peace prize laureateduring his first two years in office obama signed into law economic stimulus legislation in response to the great recession in the form of the american recovery and reinvestment act of 2009 and the tax relief
```

The output should be in the format in a new column obama['word count']:

{ 2009:4 , the :40 , chicago :10
and so on  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why shouldn't you use the Counter class; it's exactly what you need?

```
from pandas import Series
from collections import Counter
text="barack hussein obama ii brk husen bm born august 4 1961 is the 44th and current president of the united states and the first african american to hold the office born in honolulu hawaii obama is a graduate of columbia university and harvard law school where he served as president of the harvard law review he was a community organizer in chicago before earning his law degree he worked as a civil rights attorney and taught constitutional law at the university of chicago law school from 1992 to 2004 he served three terms representing the 13th district in the illinois senate from 1997 to 2004 running unsuccessfully for the united states house of representatives in 2000in 2004 obama received national attention during his campaign to represent illinois in the united states senate with his victory in the march democratic party primary his keynote address at the democratic national convention in july and his election to the senate in november he began his presidential campaign in 2007 and after a close primary campaign against hillary rodham clinton in 2008 he won sufficient delegates in the democratic party primaries to receive the presidential nomination he then defeated republican nominee john mccain in the general election and was inaugurated as president on january 20 2009 nine months after his election obama was named the 2009 nobel peace prize laureate during his first two years in office obama signed into law economic stimulus legislation in response to the great recession in the form of the american recovery and reinvestment act of 2009 and the tax relief"
df = Series(text).to_frame()
newdf = df.assign(word_count = lambda x: x[0].str.split(' ').apply(Counter)[0])
newdf['word_count']
```

> 0    {'44th': 1, 'born': 2, 'november': 1, 'running...

Comment: How do i copy the dictionary into the column obama['word count']